# region growing image segmentation

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

i make region growing algorithm for my project
this is my algorithm

(my picture have been greyscale before it)
1. get value pixel (0,0) for seed pixel
2. compare value seed pixel with one neighbor pixel
3. if value of no.3 less than treshold (T), go to next pixel and go to no.2
4. if value of no.3 more than treshold (T), change pixel to white(also for next 10 pixel), and get new seed value pixel.

my goal is my picture segmented with white line

this is my code

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // GDI+ still lies to us - the return format is BGR, NOT RGB.
            BitmapData bmData = RImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, RImage.Width, RImage.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

```
        int stride = bmData.Stride;
        System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;

        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;

            int nOffset = stride - RImage.Width * 3;

            for (int y = 0; y < RImage.Height; ++y)
            {                   
                for (int x = 0; x < RImage.Width; ++x)
                {  
                    //every new line of x must new seed
                    if (x == 0)
                    {                            
                        //getting new value seed pixel
                        seedR = p[x];
                        seedG = p[x+1];
                        seedB = p[x+2];
                    }

                    //compare value of seed pixel and pixel scan
                    if ((seedR - p[x] >= tred) || (p[x] - seedR >= tred))
                    {

                        //make white line with change value of pixel
                        for (int i=1; i <= 5; ++i)
                        {
                            p[x] = p[x + 1] = p[x + 2] = 0;
                            x++;
                        }

                        //getting new value of seed pixel
                        seedR = p[x];
                        seedG = p[x + 1];
                        seedB = p[x + 2];
                    }
                    p += 3;
                }
                p += nOffset;
            }
        }

        RImage.UnlockBits(bmData);
    }
```

my problem is my image become white in 1/3 of image
what must i doing for "region growing" ??
thx

Comment: From what I can see, your algorithm is fundamentally broken.  Your "seed" pixels are just the first pixels in the scanlines.  How is comparing the remaining pixels against the first, and repeating that for each row going to achieve image segmentation?  Also, please reformat your code.  The first couple of lines aren't indented correctly, and the rest is indented by more than what is necessary.  Also, seedG and seedB are not used anywhere, so removing them is best for readability.

Answer (score 0):

I've left some questions about your algorithm in the comments, but as I was writing them I realized that what you're trying to do may not be *image segmentation* at all.

> my goal is my picture segmented with white line

Do you mean you want something like this:

[image]

If yes, then what you're interested in isn't *image segmentation*, it's [edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator).  If you want to implement something like that, then have a read about [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) as well.